# Save a value of a local variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence

How can I save a value of a variable in objective-c, for example a `BOOL`, and when I return for the app the value of my variable is the last value setted?! For exemple:

```
BOOL *firstAccess;

firstAccess = TRUE;
```

I finish the app and return, and i wished that my variable were `TRUE`, again.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing something in your second line there?

Comment: For just a bool, `NSUserDefaults`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to save data permanently:

```
BOOL firstAccess;

/// ...

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:firstAccess forKey:@"FIRSTACCESS"];
```

To retrieve the value:

```
firstAccess = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FIRSTACCESS"];
```

See the documentation for [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `BOOL` value in [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
#define MYFirstAccessKey @"firstAccessKey"

+ (void)initialize {
    // Set the default value.  This is returned if nothing has been written for the key.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{ MYFirstAccessKey : @YES }];
}

- (void)someMethod {
    // Read the value.
    BOOL firstAccess = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:MYFirstAccessKey];
    if (firstAccess) {
        // ... do stuff ...
    }

    // ... later ...

    // Set value.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:MYFirstAccessKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];  // Write to disk now.

}
```